# A cohomology or homology associated to a Riemannian manifold or a dynamical system

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, dynamical-systems, homology-cohomology, smooth-manifolds

I  would  like  to know  whether  the  following co boundary or  boundary maps can  introduce some new kinds of cohomology or  homology which contains  some  non trivial, new,  finite  dimensional  and  helpful information  about the  manifold or  the  dynamics of  a vector  field on it.

All maps $\phi$  described below are  defined on the chain of  differential  forms on a  manifold $M$  which obviously   satisfy $\phi \circ \phi=0$.

In this  question, to sake finite  dimensionality of  resulting cohomology or  homology, instead of  consideration of  the  whole  complex $\Omega^*(M)$,  we are flexible  to consider   an **appropriate sub complex**  of $\Omega^*(M)$. Each operator  $\phi$ listed below    can  suggest  some  subcomplex  as  domain of definition of  $\phi$.

Let  $M$  be  a  Riemannian  manifold with  Laplace operator $\Delta$ and  $X$ be a  vector  field  on $M$.

Our differential  maps(coboundary or  boundary maps) are  the  following maps. The first $2$  maps  depends  on the  Riemannian structure  and  the last $2$  maps, which decrease the degree by 2,   depend  on the  vector  fields $X$.

**Suggestion for  $\phi:$**

The  map $\phi$ is:

1)$d\circ \Delta$

2)$d^* \circ \Delta$

3)$d^*\circ L_X \circ d^*$

4)$i_X\circ \Delta \circ i_X$

The operator  $L_X$ is the  Lie derivative operator. The operator $i_X:\Omega^i(M) \to \Omega^{i-1}(M)$ is the  interior product and  $d^*$ is  the  codifferential operator.

Comment: I have not much to contribute, but I would suggest to have a look at Witten's paper "supersymmetry and Morse theory" where he introduces a twisted differential operator .

Comment: @ThomasRot Thanks for  this  reference.